# Make a table using HTML

Tags: html

[image]

Hi! I am currently learning HTML coding. Can someone help me on how to make a table just like in the picture that I had attached. :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can begin creating a table like the one shown in the picture by constructing a single cell for the top and bottom rows using the [`colspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan) attribute. Then you can insert a new centered table with only two cells (without an innermost border) into the outermost cells.

Here's a complete example:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  height: 85px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90px;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
}

.border {
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

.no-bottom {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.no-top {
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <table class="center">
        <tr>
          <td class="border no-bottom"></td>
          <td class="border no-bottom"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="border"></td>
    <td class="border"></td>
    <td class="border"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <table class="center">
        <tr>
          <td class="border no-top"></td>
          <td class="border no-top"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the below snippet to get the idea of how the html structure would be like.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>    
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100px;width: 200px;border-bottom: 0; border-right:0;"></td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100px;width: 200px;border-bottom: 0;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>    
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100px;width: 200px;border-collapse: collapse; border-right:0; "></td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100px;width: 200px;border-collapse: collapse;"></td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100px;width: 200px;border-collapse: collapse; border-left:0;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>    
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: auto">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100px;width: 200px;border-top: 0; border-right:0;"></td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100px;width: 200px;border-top: 0;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Also the check the link here for working demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPQrPj

I have used the inline styles , you can create css classes and assign them to desired elements.

Answer (score 1):

Tables have columns which make the cells horizontally aligned. Your thing doesn't have that horizontal alignment so a table is not a good fit.

I'd just use nested divs. One parent to group your thing, consisting of three divs for the rows, each of which contain two or three divs for the cells.

```
<div class="thing">
    <div>
        <div>a</div><div>b</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>c</div><div>d</div><div>e</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>f</div><div>g</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now using CSS, we can center the cells within the rows

```
.thing > div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The tricky thing is collapsing the borders of the cells. This would be easy to do with a real table, but for our divs we need to write more CSS.

See the whole thing here https://jsfiddle.net/ffy9xus7/